# How can I bind appended elements?

Tags: jquery, html, plupload

I'm using Plupload for uploading files. For specific reasons I must put `FilesAdded` "inside" `init` as shown below.

The problem is that I'm not able to use `jQuery.remove()` on elements appended with jQuery.

I've normaly solved this by using `.on()`, but since there is no action such as `click` etc. I'm not sure how to bind appended element.

Any guidance much appreciated :)

```
// Custom example logic
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
    browse_button : 'btn-file-browse',
    container : 'drag-drop-container',
    drop_element : 'drag-drop-container',
    max_file_size : sim_gal_data['max_file_size'],
    url : sim_gal_data['upload_url'],
    multi_selection : true,     
    init : {
      FilesAdded: function(up, files) {

            // Create list of files being uploaded
            jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
                jQuery('#filelist').append(
                    '<div id="' + file.id + '" class="file_upload">' +
                    '<div class="file_name">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ')' +
                    '</div> <label class="file_progress"><b></b></label>'
                );
            });

            // Ready set go!
            up.refresh();
            up.start(); 
    }
});
```

**update**

This triggers the remve:

```
uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function(up, files) {
    jQuery('#filelist .file_name').remove();

    // I'm able to run this - so maybe .file_name is appended?
    jQuery('#filelist .file_name).append('TEST');
});
```

Comment: if the element is on the dom when you query it for calling the remove method it should work. what triggers the remove?

Comment: where is your remove code

Comment: @Pete I've added the remove code in my question

Comment: that code should work fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/d2Bs9/1/ as you can see i create the div dynamically and then if you click the remove it takes away the div.  On a separate note you don't have a closing div tag for your file_upload div

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm not able to use `.remove()` but I'm able to use this in stead: `jQuery('#filelist').html('');`.

Comment: ah if you're just wanting to clean out your #filelist div you could try `jQuery('#filelist').empty();` - `.html('')` is equivelant to doing `.empty().append('');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to clean-up upon UploadComplete ? If so, it should be something like below.

If you are trying to clean-up upon each file uploaded, you should handle it in [FileUploaded event handlere](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.Uploader.html-FileUploaded)

```
init : {
  UploadComplete: function(uploader, files){
     alert('upload complete');
     jQuery('#filelist').html('');
  },
  FilesAdded: function(up, files) {

        // Create list of files being uploaded
        jQuery.each(files, function(i, file) {
            jQuery('#filelist').append(
                '<div id="' + file.id + '" class="file_upload">' +
                '<div class="file_name">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ')' +
                '</div> <label class="file_progress"><b></b></label>'
            );
        });

        // Ready set go!
        up.refresh();
        up.start(); 
}
```